# I have problem with converting MATLAB code to Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, image-processing

I need to convert the block of code that's shown below to Python. I created two arrays named `u` and `v` seperately and put them in a for loop in the range 0 to M-1 and I know `find` works similar to if condition. I have a problem since both `idx` and `u` are arrays.

MATLAB code is this:

```matlab
u = 0:(M-1); 
v = 0:(N-1); 
idx = find(u > M/2); 
u(idx) = u(idx) - M; #I have a problem here
idy = find(v > N/2); 
v(idy) = v(idy) - N;
```

Basically what I have done in Python until I got to this problematic line is:

```py
input_image = Image.open('./....image....')
input_image=np.array(input_image)
M,N = input_image.shape[0],input_image.shape[1]

FT_img = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(input_image))

# Assign the order value 
n = 2; # one can change this value accordingly 
  
# Assign Cut-off Frequency 
D0 = 60; # one can change this value accordingly 
  
# Designing filter 
u=[]
v=[]
for i in range(M-1):
  u.append(i)

for i in range(N-1):
  v.append(i)
```

Comment: You are looking for Numpy. I Think you should read some Python tutorials. [1](https://github.com/jakevdp/WhirlwindTourOfPython), [2](https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook). The latter has a chapter dedicated to Numpy.

Comment: Thank you @Cris I just edited my post.

Comment: Clearly, a ***Matlab*** script is your input and a ***Python***  script is your output. Please post the ***Matlab***  and ***Python***  scripts as two separate code blocks. Currently, you have the *** Matlab***  and ***Python*** merged together into one code block. Separate the two code blocks inside of your stack overflow post with pound signs. `### Original Matlab (input) ###` and `### Attempted Python (output) ###`

Comment: @Samuel, just edited my post in the way you mentioned.

Comment: Apparently, the MATLAB code you have computes something known as the sample frequencies of a "***Discrete Fourier Transform***". Discrete Fourier Transforms are well-studied. You do ***not*** have to write your own code to compute the sample frequencies of Discrete Fourier Transform. If the person who wrote the MATLAB code failed to write a comment explaining what they were computing, then that person was a very bad programmer. It is almost impossible to tell what code is supposed to do without comments. Why not just have a function named something like `get_fft_frequencies()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MATLAB code

```matlab
u = 0:(M-1);
idx = find(u > M/2);
u(idx) = u(idx) - M;
```

can be more efficiently implemented by leaving out `find`:

```matlab
u = 0:(M-1);
idx = u > M/2;
u(idx) = u(idx) - M;
```

This form is trivially translatable to Python with NumPy:

```py
u = np.arange(0, M)
idx = u > M/2
u[idx] = u[idx] - M
```

Comment: Suppose for a moment that `M/2` is the number `34`. Note that the `>` operator has a special definition for ***numpy*** arrays. When `u` is a ***numpy*** array, the code `u > 34` searchers array `u` for every single element greater than `34`. We know ahead of time that `u` is the array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]` The elements of `u` are already in sorted order and they are numbered sequentially. It is a waste of time to search the entire array `u` for elements bigger than `34`. For run-time efficiency, you could write, `idx = range(1 + M/2, M)` or  `idx = range(1+ len(u)/2, len(u))`

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon: I agree. You can also concatenate the two half arrays and avoid the subtraction. And it’s even easier to just call `fftfreq`.

Answer (score 3):

### What does `u = 0:(M-1)` do in ***Matlab*** and how can we do the same thing in ***Python***?

The following is one excerpt from your original ***Matlab*** code:

```matlab
    % BEGIN MATLAB %

    u = 0:(M-1); 

    % END MATLAB %
```

What does the code do?

Suppose that `M = 7`. Then the Matlab code simplifies:

```matlab
    u = 0:6;
```

The result is an array `u` beginning at `0` and ending at `6`:

```python
u = [0   1   2   3   4   5   6]
```

Essentially, you are initializing an array of consecutive integers.

There are various ways to accomplish something similar in ***Python***:

```python
    # Begin Python   

    M = 7
    u = list(range(0, M))

    # End python
```

Note that `range(0, 7)` looks like `[0, ..., 5, 6]`, not `[0, ..., 6, 7]`
Python's `range` function automatically subtracts `1` from the upper limit

If you really are doing ***Matlab***-type stuff, then `numpy` is the library you want to use in ***Python***:

```python
import numpy as np
u = np.array(range(0, 7))
```

### Indexing beginning at ***0*** versus indexing beginning at *1*

Note that ***Matlab*** indexing begins at `1`.
***Python*** indexing begins at `0`.
`ARRAY  = ["red", "blue", "white", "green"]`

```
+--------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
|    ARRAY     | "red" | "blue" | "white" | "green" |
+--------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| PYTHON INDEX |     0 |      1 |       2 |       3 |
| MATLAB INDEX |     1 |      2 |       3 |       4 |
+--------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
```

### Understanding the `find` function

#### Translating `find` from ***Matlab*** into ***English***

Consider the `find` function from ***Matlab***:

```matlab
idx = find(u > M/2);    % this is matlab-code
```

The function-call `find(u)` will search the entire array `u` for anything strictly larger than `M/2`. `find(u)` will then return a list of all indices for things larger than `M/2`

Consider the following example of the `find` function:

```matlab
u  = [98 00 00 87 49 50 51 00 85];
%      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 .....ARRAY INDICIES
idx = find(u > 50);
disp(idx)
% displays .... 1   4   7   9
```

`find(u > 50)` will find the indices of every element of `u` greater than or equal to `51`

Consider the code `u(idx) = 22;`
We have the following results:

```
+---------------------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+------+
|   MATLAB INDICIES   |  1   |  2  |  3  |  4   |  5  |  6  |  7   |  8  |  9   |
+---------------------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+------+
| print(u)            | 99   | 00  | 00  | 99   | 49  | 50  | 51   | 00  | 99   |
+---------------------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+------+
| % u > 50?           | %yes | %no | %no | %yes | %no | %no | %yes | %no | %yes |
+---------------------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+------+
| idx = find(u > 50); |      |     |     |      |     |     |      |     |      |
| u(idx) = 22;        |      |     |     |      |     |     |      |     |      |
+---------------------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+------+
| print(u)            | 22   | 0   | 0   | 22   | 49  | 50  | 22   | 0   | 22   |
+---------------------+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+------+
```

Everything inside of array `u` greater than or equal to `51` was replaced with `22`

#### Translating `find` from ***English*** to ***Python***

Suppose that you have an array `u` in ***Python***.
You want to replace every integer greater than or equal to `51`  with `22`
You can do that in ***Python*** using the `numpy` library:

```python
# This is Python (not matlab)
import numpy as np

u = [98 00 00 87 49 50 51 00 85];
u = np.array(u)
u[u > 50] = 22

# THIS IS PYTHON CODE (not matlab)
```

Note that `u[u > 50] = 22` is the same as the following:

```python
# THIS IS PYTHON CODE (not matlab)   

indicies = type(u).__gt__(u, 50)
u.__setitem__(indicies, 22)  

# THIS IS PYTHON CODE (not matlab)
```

#### Translating `find` from ***Matlab*** to ***Python***

If you translate part of your original code from ***Matlab*** to ***Python*** it would look like the following:

***MATLAB INPUT:***

```matlab
M = 7      
u = 0:(M-1);     
idx = find(u > M/2); 
u(idx) = u(idx) - M;
```

***PYTHON OUTPUT:***

```python
# THIS IS PYTHON CODE (not matlab)   
 
import numpy as np
M = 7    
u = np.array(range(0, M))   
idx = u > M/2
u[idx] = u[idx] - M  

# THIS IS PYTHON CODE (not matlab)
```

### Translating all ***ALL*** of the ***Matlab*** code into ***English*** and ***Mathematics***

In the beginning of the post I explained what a few individual pieces of your ***Matlab*** code do.

Now, let us translate the entire ***Matlab*** script into English and Math.

*** SOMETHING SIMILAIR TO YOUR ORIGINAL/OLD MATLAB IS BELOW ***

```matlab
function u = GenerateArray(M)
    u = 0:(M-1); 
    idx = find(u > M/2); 
    u(idx) = u(idx) - M; 
end

M = 7;
u = GenerateArray(M);

N = 9;
v = GenerateArray(N);
```

*** THE BEHAVIOR AS A TABLE***

I think that the ***Matlab*** code is easier to understand as a table, than as code:

```
+--------------+---------------------------+
| WHOLE NUMBER |           ARRAY           |
| `M`          |  `u`                      |
+--------------+---------------------------+
| 4            | 0   1   2  -1             |
| 5            | 0   1   2  -2  -1         |
| 6            | 0   1   2   3  -2  -1     |
| 7            | 0   1   2   3  -3  -2  -1 |
+--------------+---------------------------+
```

For `M > 7`:

- the left half of the array is: `[0, 1 , 2,  3,  [...],  floor(M/2)]`
- the right half of the array is: `lang-none [(-1)*(x-0), (-1)*(x-1), (-1)*(x-2), [...], -3, -2, -1]`       where ***x*** equals `floor((M-1)/2)`

### Translating all of the ***Matlab*** code into ***Python***

The following ***Python*** script has the same output as the ***Matlab*** script:

```python
import numpy as np
import itertools as itts

def generate_data(array_size : int) -> type(np.array(range(0, 1))):
    """
    +--------------+---------------------------+
    | INPUT        |           OUTPUT          |
    +--------------+---------------------------+
    | 4            | 0   1   2  -1             |
    | 5            | 0   1   2  -2  -1         |
    | 6            | 0   1   2   3  -2  -1     |
    | 7            | 0   1   2   3  -3  -2  -1 |
    +--------------+---------------------------+

     * the left side of the array:
         starts at:
             zero

         ends at:
             floor(M/2)

         counts by:
             +1

         looks like:
             [0, 1 , 2,  3,  [...],  floor(M/2)]

     * the right side of the array...
         starts at
            (-1) * floor((M-1)/2)

         ends at:
             -1

         counts by:
             -1

         looks like:
             [
                 (-1) * floor((M-1)/2),
                 (-1) * (floor((M-1)/2) - 1),
                 (-1) * (floor((M-1)/2) - 2),
                 [...],
                 -3,
                 -2,
                 -1
            ]

    """
    # clean_input = int(dirty_input)
    n = int(array_size)

    # make the first element of the left side of the array be zero.
    # left_side_first = 0
    lsf = 0

    # left_side_last = clean_input // 2
    lsl = n // 2

    # left_side_iterator =  range(left_side_first, 1 + left_side_last)
    lsit = range(lsf, 1 + lsl)
    # `list` stands for "left side iterator"

    right_side_first = (-1) * ((n - 1) // 2)
    right_side_last = -1
    right_side_iterator = range(right_side_first, 1 + right_side_last)

    # merged_iterator = chain(left_side_iterator, right_side_iterator)
    merged_iterator = itts.chain(lsit, right_side_iterator)

    output = np.array(list(merged_iterator))

    # We convert the iterator to a `list` because the following
    # direct use of the iterator does not work:
    #
    #    output = np.array(merged_iterator)

    return output
```

We can call the ***Python*** function like so:

```python
arr = generate_data(14)
print(arr)
```

The output for input `14` is shown below:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1]
```